# Hibernate validator does not show logs or throw exception when parameter is wrong

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I have a Spring REST controller which uses the Hibernate Validator to validate its parameters.
There is XFilterRequest class as parameter of the REST method which has the @Valid annotation.
The XFilterRequest class has a filter member

```
@Valid
protected XFilter filter;
```

That class has a single validated member:

```
 @Size(max = 255, message = "searchString size must be at most 255")
 private String searchString;
```

But when sending more than 255 characters, 400 is returned (which is correct) but the HTTP response is empty.
I added the

```
server.error.include-binding-errors: always
```

to the application.yml but it changes nothing.
Looking at the log I see

2022-11-09 18:36:12.186+0000 ←[35m-TRACE←[0;39m --- [http-nio-8300-exec-9] [b3ae4bd87e9123d2,b3ae4bd87e9123d2,,] o.h.v.i.e.c.SimpleConstraintTree         : Validating value ma8L8fTQ3TgNoURmPRVLqKuH6r6QCy0sbZ749zWZXFY1h57SlVee1sA0R2VB406W4uDwsuj1QIVHzWRb7X2hdWb9E8LwcJo2oX0u7NFEFi68XGefF7mMyPKN1XOAKCOuaPG4WVIpnnGBKSMGb7MlpQzavl9ygv1OWsK2gTNHzgyyJhVFmWmS20qF5vOujLtbx8ysbDiiCowHvLcgPCPO9bb0b1b64O13X99eeTPlQAxSf71DRFUCCn752nZ8skkk against constraint defined by ConstraintDescriptorImpl{annotation=j.v.c.Size, payloads=[], hasComposingConstraints=true, isReportAsSingleInvalidConstraint=false, constraintLocationKind=FIELD, definedOn=DEFINED_LOCALLY, groups=[interface javax.validation.groups.Default], attributes={groups=[Ljava.lang.Class;@337af7ce, min=0, message=searchString size must be at most 255, payload=[Ljava.lang.Class;@7b92c029, max=255}, constraintType=GENERIC, valueUnwrapping=DEFAULT}.

In other words it's validating the searchString member (which has length 257, bigger than the max 255). But no exception is shown in the log and no message sent to the caller by the Hibernate Validator.
Maybe the class structure XFilterRequest, XFilter is confusing the framework.

UPDATE:
debugging I see there is an exception when converting to XFilterRequest, as XFilter is not valid, there is a binding exception. However the message associated to the Size constraint does not make it up to the response.
I have also tried to add `server.error.include-message: always` but I still get an empty response with 400 status code. There seems to be a problem with Spring Boot / Spring Web silencing the messages of some exceptions. But at least debugging I was able to see the object is really validated (which was to be suspected since the response has 400 status code).

Comment: It would help people answer if you include the full classes in the question, including the controller.

Comment: I have created a minimal sample application where I was hoping to reproduce the issue. Unfortunately in my (proprietary) code, I get in Postman for example a 400 response with empty body, whereas in my sample app (with the same structure), I get a body with plenty of details.